# Скрытые элементы за пределами области видимости родителя со стилем overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, css, scss

Как с помощью jquery, получить список элементов которые находятся за пределами области видимости родительского элемента, у которого установлен стиль **overflow:hidden**

Вот HTML:

```
<div class="item-footer">
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Забрать</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Оплатить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Счет</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Добавлено</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Добавить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Подтвердить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Отмена</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Разделить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Объединить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Вернуть</span></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: легко и просто, если они есть в вашем HTML, если их там нет, то сложно и очень сложно :) Покажите ваш HTML и вам обязательно расскажут как это сделать

Comment: @MasterAlex, добавил html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант у меня получился:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var footerItems = $('.item-footer').children('.footer-btn'),
    itemsLength = 0,
    lostItems = [];

  footerItems.each(function() {
    itemsLength = itemsLength + $(this).outerWidth();
    if (itemsLength > $('.item-footer').outerWidth()) {
      lostItems.push($(this).children('span').text());
    };
  });

  console.log(lostItems);
});
```

```css
.item-footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
}
.item-footer div {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-footer">
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Забрать</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Оплатить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Счет</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Добавлено</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Добавить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Подтвердить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Отмена</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Разделить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Объединить</span></div>
   <div class="footer-btn"><span>Вернуть</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var list = [];
  $('.block').each(function() {
    var pos = [
       {
          left: $(this).offset().left, 
          right: $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth(), 
          top: $(this).offset().top, 
          bottom: $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
       }, 
       {
          left: $('.list').offset().left, 
          right: $('.list').offset().left + $('.list').outerWidth(), 
          top: $('.list').offset().top, 
          bottom: $('.list').offset().top + $('.list').outerHeight()
       }
    ];
    if(pos[0].right > pos[1].right || pos[0].left < pos[1].left || pos[0].top < pos[1].top || pos[0].bottom > pos[1].bottom){
      list[list.length] = $(this).attr('name');
    };
  });
  console.log(list);
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.list .list2 {width: 600px;}
.list .list2 .block {display: inline-block;width:70px;height:70px;margin:3px;background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list">
  <div class="list2">
    <div class="block" name="1"></div>
    <div class="block" name="2"></div>
    <div class="block" name="3"></div>
    <div class="block" name="4"></div>
    <div class="block" name="5"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибки :) У меня примерно тоже получилось, думал что можно проще реализовать. Если не подскажут более простое решение, то ваш вариант лучший. Спасибо.

Comment: @ДмитрийВишняков, не знаю как легче, но знаю как сложнее организовать :D

Comment: У меня первый скрипт на 50 строк вышел, после этого подумал что надо что-то менять :))))) Второй скрипт на 30 строк :)

Comment: @ДмитрийВишняков, было и больше )